# Custom JS not recognized by WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've got an issue (that I never had before on WordPress sites) with my custom JS script.
I registered it as usual in my functions.php like so :

```
function load_js(){

wp_register_script('script-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), rand(111,9999), true);
wp_enqueue_script('script-js'); 
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

At first, my script was loading alright and I could edit whatever jQuery I wanted, but suddenly it stopped working. I tried deactiving all the plugins, still not uploaded by WordPress.

Here is the link to my homepage : [My Website](http://devmode.mr-zamal.com/).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Could be multiple things. Do you have the `wp_footer()` function in your template?

Comment: Are you sure the path to `script.js` is correct?

Comment: Looking at your source code, it looks like the closing `<body>` and `<html>` tags are missing. @EmielZuurbier might be correct, but it's super hard to test without seeing your actual footer.php code or if `wp_footer()` is in your template. You can test by removing the `TRUE` argument

Comment: I'll add that I can't seem to find a /js/script.js in the child theme or in the parent theme directory.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answers. I'll look up and let you know !

Comment: It's the wp_footer() function missing in my template. Any idea how to include this function properly ?